# Input a jquery sentence in a grails gsp tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails, groovy, syntax

I'm getting multiplecompilation error when I try to use a jQuery sentence in a grails `<g:link>` tag

```
var ul = $("#authorList > ul");
ul.append('<li><g:link action="show" controller="author" id="'+$('#authorID').val()+'">+'+$('#authorField').val()+'</g:link></li>')
```

I'm only getting error with the jquery inside the id="" attribute, with this

```
ul.append('<li><g:link action="show" controller="author" id="">+'+$('#authorField').val()+'</g:link></li>')
```

The page is working but I can't get the dynamic links, how it's the correct syntax?

---

> URI: /ComplexTables/book/create Class 
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException 
>   Message: startup failed:
>   19: illegal string body character after dollar sign; solution: either
>   escape a literal dollar sign "\$5" or bracket the value expression
>   "${5}" @ line 19, column 210. l()\'"', 35, it) { return "'+$('#authorI
>   ^ 1 error

---

Around line 35 of grails-app\views\book_form.gsp

```
function appendAuthor(ev) {
34:        var ul = $("#authorList > ul");
35:        ul.append('<li><g:link action="show" controller="author" id="'+$('#authorID').val()'">+'+$('#authorField').val()+'</g:link></li>')
36:    }
37:</script>
```

Comment: gsp's are precompiled on the server.  I would be highly surprised that jQuery would be able to do this.

Comment: put js into external resource and it will be fine

Comment: using a external file the gsp do not compile the <g:link tag put the <g:link tag directly in the html

Comment: i'll try just use a normal <a href=""> without the gsp tag

Comment: use a normal <a> worked, i would like to ask to the server fo the tag with the <g:link> but i think its not posible

Answer (score 1):

I don't know GSP but generally ID can not start with a number.

> "Using characters except ASCII letters, digits, '_', '-' and '.' may
>   cause compatibility problems, as they weren't allowed in HTML 4.
>   Though this restriction has been lifted in HTML 5, an ID should start
>   with a letter for compatibility."

And is not it better if you used just DOM getElementById () Method instead of jQuery

```
ul.append('<li><g:link action="show" controller="author" id="sth_'+document.getElementById('authorID').value+'">+'+document.getElementById('authorID').value+'</g:link></li>')
```

Comment: in this case the id atributte is not the normal id of all tags, in this gsp tag you put on id the primary key of the element you want to show, the gsp compile this tag into a normal <a href="" tag with the route to the element this should return <a href="some route/show/dinamyc id obtained by jquery"

Comment: i tried with document.getElementbyId and gsp also return a compile error Expecting '=' after attribute name (action="show" controller="author" id="'+document.getElementById("authorID").value+'")